# Percentage of each row that meet a condition in a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame ( call "dat") and a vector ( call v) with 6 elements

I want to add **6 new columns**  to the data frame  which

**1st** new column: number of elements in each row that are greater than **1st** element of vector

**2nd** new column: number of elements in each row that are greater than **2nd** element of vector

**3rd** new column: number of elements in each row that are greater than **3rd** element of vector

and so on.....

```
dat<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:6,50,rep=TRUE)))
v<-c(2,4,1,3,5,6)
```

Thank you

Comment: What is percent of any row in dat?

Comment: I mean number of element in each row that are greater than 1st element of the v  divide by total number of elements in each row

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you could do :

```
dat[paste0('greater_than_', v)] <- lapply(v, function(x) rowSums(dat >= x))
```

In `purrr`, you could do :

```
dat[paste0('greater_than_', v)] <- map(v, ~rowSums(dat >= .x))
```

Comment: Ronak, How can we do it in `purrr`?  For one value we can do it like `dat %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(y1 = sum(across() > 2)/10)`

Comment: The syntax would be the same for `purrr` as well. I updated the answer with that.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse`, in this way

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map_dfc(v, ~rowSums(dat >= .x)) %>% 
     rename_all(~str_c('greater_than_', v)) %>% 
     bind_cols(dat, .)
```

---

Or using a `for` loop in `base R`

```
for(i in seq_along(v)) dat[paste0('greater_than_', v[i])] <- rowSums(dat >= v[i])
```